# Python: dict default argument... how did I not know they work like this?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

```
class Klass(object):

    def a(self, d={}):
        print d
        self.b(d)

    def b(self, d={}):
        import random
        print d
        d[str(random.random())] = random.random()
```

I assumed that every time I call `c.a()` without arguments, I got a fresh empty `dict`. However, this is what actually happens:

```
>>> c = Klass()
>>> c.a()
{}
{}
>>> c.a()
{'0.637151613258': 0.61491180520119226}
{'0.637151613258': 0.61491180520119226}
>>> c.a()
{'0.637151613258': 0.61491180520119226, '0.960051474644': 0.54702415744398669}
{'0.637151613258': 0.61491180520119226, '0.960051474644': 0.54702415744398669}
...
```

I don't really want to do some sort of `lambda`/`iscallable` thing. What is a good pattern to use here?

Of course, I figured out I decent way around the problem by the time I had started typing out the question. But, if anyone has a different pet way around this, I would love to hear.

Comment: I guess you _did_ know this by the time you asked the question, since you answered it straight away :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could get a fresh, empty `dict` with:

```
    def a(self, d=None):
        if d is None:
            d = {}
```

The problem is well described [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577786-smarter-default-arguments/) under **Mutable Default Arguments**.